# Series and solution of $-\Delta u + \lambda u = f(x)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, elliptic-pde

Consider a bounded smooth set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ (for example, we can take a ball). Can we write down the solution of
\begin{align*}
-\Delta u(x) + \lambda u(x) &= f(x), & x \in \Omega \\
u(x)&= 0, & x \in \partial \Omega,
\end{align*}
with $\lambda >0$ and $f$ smooth as,  $$u(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty(-\lambda)^i G^{i+1} f(x),$$
where $G f(x)$ denotes the convolution of $f$ with the Green function of the Laplacian? In other words, is it true that $(I+\lambda G)$ is invertible? What is a good reference for this result?

Comment: This is to show that $I+\lambda G$ is invertible: By compactness and Fredholm theory it suffices to show that the kernel is trivial. But that easily follows from energy estimates.

Comment: @Ali Thank you. Could you expand this comment into an answer by adding some details?

Comment: Since $ \lambda > - \lambda_1$ you should be able to apply Riesz directly to get the existence of a solution on $H_0^1$.